# How to detect user finger lift off when scrolling [Flatlist]

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to detect user finger lift off after scrolling? I've added pan responder with handlers on release is not firing.

Answer (score 1):

With 'onMomentumScrollBegin' and 'onMomentumScrollEnd' props you can decide what to happen when the user scrolls the FlatList with hand.

```
userLiftedFingerOffScreen() {
 // do whatever
}

render() =>
  <FlatList
    data={listData}
    renderItem={({item}) => <SomeItem item={item} />}
    onMomentumScrollEnd={this.userLiftedFingerOffScreen}
  />
```

I myself used this to make a slide show with Flatlist and it's pagination ability and I needed a non-automatic scrolling and onMomentumScroll was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know WHEN the user has lifted their finger off the screen after scroll, you can use the [onScrollEndDrag Function](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onscrollenddrag). FlatList iinherits props from ScrollView so all of ScrollView's props are accessible in a FlatList. You shouldn't need to use pan responder for this.

ex:

```
userLiftedFingerOffScreen() {
 // do whatever
}

render() =>
  <FlatList
    data={listData}
    renderItem={({item}) => <SomeItem item={item} />}
    onScrollEndDrag={this.userLiftedFingerOffScreen}
  />
```